# Conservative Azure Windows VM to Run SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, performance, virtual-machines, database, azure

For testing purposes I need to set up three Azure Windows VMs to each run an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 each holding one DB of approx 100GB. There will be quite a few complex stored procedures/queries/joins running against each database, but there won't be more than 2 connections at any given time.

Ideally I would like to do this as cheaply as possible, but I don't want to compromise performance. I'm not a DBA or very knowledgeable about machine performance, so I was wondering if anyone had any advice as to which tier would be a safe choice?

Comment: Why don't you start with the lowest tier that you think will meet your needs and go from there? There's no way for us to know or guess what "size" VM will meet your needs.

Comment: I'm hoping for some guidance as to what the lowest tier to meet my needs would be . I'm not sure if there is a certain number of cores/RAM that is the base level for SQL server. I know it's pretty resource intensive, I'd like to know if that's quantifiable so I can make an educated guess on where to start.

Comment: lowest tier possible to run sql server is A3 because A2 only gives you 3.5GB or memory which is too low for most SQL Server operations. Unless you are running a dev/test environment, anything lower than A3 is not advisable. Also make sure to follow best practices guideliness to deploy these servers to optimize I/O operations. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn133149.aspx